# Can't use dbfirst to generate db models by efcore(3.0) in MacOS 10.15

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina, entity-framework-core-3.0

Is this possible that the mac os 10.15 didn't support 32 bit anymore, but when I tried to generate the db models (dbfirst) file because it use 32 bit program?

The commend as bellow:

```
% dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=xxxxxxxx;port=3306;database=xxxxxx;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -f

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Exe.Run(String executable, IReadOnlyList`1 args, String workingDirectory, Boolean interceptOutput)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might have been solved in the this release `(3.0.100-preview5-011562`

Win32 doesn't have anything to do with 32 or 64 bit operating systems but I see why you might think that. The name can be deceiving. The win 32 is a wrapper class for some exceptions. Through it you can has access to something called the **NativeError** code which is a 32 bit integer. This is why it is called win32. 64 bit operating systems can still handle 32 bit ints

It is a system exception class that is used when some operations go wrong. These operations typically involve system level calls like open file or process

The fix was for a permissions issue and not this but just try and upgrade .NET Core and see if that helps.

Find the issue and pull request for the fix here

Issue:https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/11231

Fix:https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/pull/6003

For your issue, I suspect you upgraded to 64 bit MACOS but somewhere along the way, there was a discrepancy between your .NET version 32/64bit and some of the packages you have.

Please delete your global nuget and also make sure you have 64 bit .NET and 64 bit binaries. Otherwise, there's something called `file system redirection` that might try and match your 32 bit binaries to relevant 32 bit binaries which might not exist if you upgraded either .NET or the packages